# React router - page doesn't change when navigating from outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to redirect user to "Not Authorized" page after there's 403 api response. Here's what I got so far:

**created my own history for using `history.push` outside React components**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

export default class OwnBrowserRouter extends BrowserRouter {
  history
}
```

Then I got an api handler like this:

```
import { history } from "./my-own-history"

const responseErrorHandler = error => {
  const status = _get(error, "response.status")
  if (status === 403) {
    history.push(getRoutePath("not-authorized"))
  }

  throw error
}

const requestFactory = (
  method,
  url,
  body = {},
  useToken = true,
  ownToken = ""
) => {
  ... not important code here ...

  return axios(url, config)
    .then(responseSuccessHandler)
    .catch(responseErrorHandler)
}
```

And at last I have an `Article` page, where I'm calling redux action `retrieveArticle(id)`. If the user is not authorized to see the article, the browser's route is changed to `/not-authorized` correctly, but the Article component stays rendered (page doesn't change). 
When I add `.then(() => this.props.history.push("/not-authorized"))` to the redux action call, it started to work, but I don't want to add this to every api call in my app ... I want to solve it globally for all api calls in my api handler.

Comment: Did you try `withRouter`?

Comment: @AmanshuKataria I can't, my api handler is not react component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
export default class OwnBrowserRouter extends BrowserRouter {
  history
}
```

To

```
export default class OwnBrowserRouter extends BrowserRouter {
  history = history;
}
```

As stated in the [Class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#fields-without-initializers-are-set-to-undefined), certain transpilers may ignore the field completely. Thus the original history (the one created in the original BrowserRouter) will be used.

> Both public and private field declarations create a field in the
>   instance, whether or not there's an initializer present. If there's no
>   initializer, the field is set to undefined. This differs a bit from
>   certain transpiler implementations, which would just entirely ignore a
>   field declaration which has no initializer.